# How can I use gzip in go to compress from a command using stdoutpipe?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how to use compression (gzip) for processes which must write to a valid pipe, all in go.

If a pipe is not detected, the enclosing process will error, stating the pipe is broken. So as far as I can tell, I **have** to use StdoutPipe?

For this example, I am just trying to gzip the output from echo.

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    //  "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("/tmp/local_test.gz")

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "my\nstrings\nare\nfancy")

    r, w := io.Pipe()
    gzw := gzip.NewWriter(w)

    out, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    cmd.Start()

    go func() {
        // copy stdoutpipe to gz writer?
        io.Copy(w, out)
        gzw.Close()
        w.Close()
    }()

    // copy pipe to file?
    io.Copy(f, r)
}
```

The file is written, but it's not in gzip format?

```
$ file /tmp/local_test.gz
/tmp/local_test.gz: data
$ gunzip /tmp/local_test.gz
gunzip: /tmp/local_test.gz: not in gzip format
```

Comment: Maybe you have to close w before closing gzw.

Comment: @edkeveked, that just produced an ASCII text file. I shall try a few more things with the close/wait order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your pipings are uselessly complex, don't forget to flush and close, remember defer is lifo.

You only need to wrap f writer into a gzip writer, than copy stdout to the writer.

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    os.Remove("local_test.gz")
    f, _ := os.Create("local_test.gz")
    defer f.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "my\nstrings\nare\nfancy")

    gzw := gzip.NewWriter(f)
    defer gzw.Close()
    defer gzw.Flush()

    out, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    cmd.Start()

    io.Copy(gzw, out)

    // cmd.Wait() // to catch processing errors    
}
```

the result check

```
$ file local_test.gz 
local_test.gz: gzip compressed data, original size 21
$ cat local_test.gz | gunzip -c
my
strings
are
fancy
```